# Django: How to use get_form() method in CreateView?

Tags: python, django

I have a CustomForm in my forms.py that needs the public key of the URL. I mean e.g. `/book/<pk>/create`.

In my views.py there is this CreateView:

```
class CustomCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomForm
```

Now my question is how can I pass the public key of the URL to the CustomForm. The CustomForm expect a keyword argument named `pk`.

I thing the get_form() method could help, but I am not sure and do not know how to use it:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form

Comment: Sounds like it is `get_form_kwargs` you need.

Comment: But how do I get access to the <pk> in the CreateView?

Comment: It it's in the URL, then `self.kwargs["pk"]`

Comment: Do you want the `pk` in the form for some other reason other than assigning a field/foreign key? If not, you can just use `self.kwargs['pk']` to do the assignment in `form_valid`, before saving the form. (Incidentally, `pk` stands for "primary key", not "public key".)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

in your view:

```
class CustomCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomForm
    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(CustomCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['pk'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        return kwargs
```

in your custom form:

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.pk = kwargs.pop('pk', None)
    super(CustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```